# What are the moving glowing balls in slither.io?

Tags: slither.io

In slither.io, there are these little moving balls that glow. If you eat them, you grow more than just eating a regular food pellet. One thing about them that's kinda weird, is that if you move toward them they will dodge you.

For reference, here are some screenshots of them.

The purple on here:

[image]

and the violet one here:

[image]

What are these things? Are the controlled by other players? Do they have a name? What are some strategies for them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They give more mass than other bits of food, which is why they are harder to catch.

Fun fact: Dashing causes the glowing food to magnetize to you if you get close enough.

Comment: Can you verify that these balls seem to actually emerge from the movement of larger snakes.

Answer (score 2):

The stationary balls are called 'Food' and are worth between 1 and 20 length.

The mobile balls are called 'prey' and are worth between 50 and 100 length (but you usually have to spend some length boosting to catch them).

Answer (score 1):

It's just energy. Don't know what it is called. It helps you get bigger and larger. When you boost in the game or are killed you lose them. They are parts of snakes

Answer (score -1):

Im pretty sure they are just food they are most probably not player controlled as there isn't an option to become one and they aren't tiny player snakes since you can see them when you are the smallest length possible.I think it is just food that is slightly harder to catch, they might make you longer than normal food but I am not sure

Comment: Your answer is correct, but it is hard to understand

Answer (score -7):

I think it is part of a dead snake that nobody ate. Then it suddenly starts moving. I've seen it happen before. So in conclusion, it is just part of a dead snake that nobody ate for a certain number of time.

Comment: Your looking at the wrong thing; notice how he describes the colors? -1

Comment: That's certainly possible, but this answer is mostly conjecture. Do you have any proof of source? A video showing this happening?

Comment: This is false. Prey are spawned randomly, just like food. Perhaps you saw a prey being spawned on the same spot an enemy died, but they are not from dead players.